# How to open a new tab in iTerm in the same folder as the one that is open?

Tags: terminal, iterm

I'm using iTerm for my command line needs, and when I open a tab using <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> I want it to open the tab `cd`'ed to the same location as the tab that was open when I hit <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (instead of opening in my `/Users/kramer65`).

I searched around the Preferences, but I can't seem to find it. Does anybody know how I can do this? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Select "Reuse previous session's directory" from the preferences of your profile:

[image]

Alternatively click on "Advanced Configuration" then "Edit..." so you can set the working directory separately for new windows, new tabs & new split panes

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it works but now my aliases that I have in my `~/.zshrc` to jump to specific directories are unrecognized. What side effect does the above have?

Answer (score 48):

This is a year old, but I'd like to add a response that isn't so heavy-handed. The accepted answer will open the previous directory *every* time you open a new tab, which I personally find frustrating. I feel it's easier to always open in the home directory and then open the current directory in a new tab as needed.

To do that, simply run the following command:

```
open . -a iterm
```

That will open the current directory (`open .`) using the application (`-a`) that most closely matches `iterm`.

Comment: I wonder if you could pass a command to that new iterm using the same open syntax.  Putting this inside a postactivate for a python venv you could open the iterm and have it `ssh` to a remote server as part of your `workon` workflow

Answer (score 7):

To bind a special keybinding to this:

- go to **Settings** (  <kbd>Cmd  ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>)
- then **keys**
- select the **+** sign
- choose a keybinding
- select the **duplicate tab** action.

Comment: This results in the 2 tabs mirroring each other. For eg. If I change dir in tab, it will get reflected in the other too

Answer (score 0):

If you've just set "Reuse previous session's directory" and the change doesn't seem to be taking effect, it's worth noting that the new changes will only apply to tabs / panes that get opened after you've chosen this setting.

For example:

- Let's say the current setting is: "Home Directory", and you have a tab open (tab #1)
- You go to "Preferences" and change to "Reuse previous session's directory"
- If you open a new tab (tab #2) while on tab #1, it will still use the previous settings
- However, if you open another tab (tab #3) while on Tab 2, it will respect the new configuration

Comment: It seems like it required a full restart in my case. New tabs still opened in my home dir until I restarted iTerm.